How To Update Source page in React
We Have React.js project so we want this project SEO friendly, react.js all page title and meta tage information update page wise on source page in react app
react-helmet and many more package is not work for source page update
only react without any framework
All react packages check for SEO but is not update source page but is update only UI title and meta tag in developer tools element section
so we want update source page using react only

To make your React.js project SEO-friendly by dynamically updating the <title> and meta tags on the source page, without using any packages like react-helmet or other third-party libraries, you'll need to update the <title> and <meta> tags directly within the React lifecycle methods.
Unfortunately, React itself (without SSR) does not natively support updating the source HTML as it is a client-side framework, which means changes to meta tags typically only reflect in the browser DOM (as you mentioned, in Developer Tools). However, if you want the changes to be visible in the browser and have SEO improvements, using server-side rendering (SSR) like Next.js or React Server Components is often recommended. But as you requested a solution without frameworks, here's how to achieve it for the client-side:
Steps to Dynamically Update Meta Tags and Title in React:

Manually update the document’s title in useEffect or lifecycle methods for class components.
Update the meta tags dynamically using JavaScript DOM manipulation.

Example Implementation Using React:
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function SEOPage({ title, description, keywords }) {

  // Function to dynamically set meta tags
  const setMetaTags = () => {
    // Update document title
    document.title = title;

    // Update or create meta description tag
    let descriptionMeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]');
    if (descriptionMeta) {
      descriptionMeta.setAttribute('content', description);
    } else {
      descriptionMeta = document.createElement('meta');
      descriptionMeta.name = "description";
      descriptionMeta.content = description;
      document.head.appendChild(descriptionMeta);
    }

    // Update or create meta keywords tag
    let keywordsMeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="keywords"]');
    if (keywordsMeta) {
      keywordsMeta.setAttribute('content', keywords);
    } else {
      keywordsMeta = document.createElement('meta');
      keywordsMeta.name = "keywords";
      keywordsMeta.content = keywords;
      document.head.appendChild(keywordsMeta);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setMetaTags();
  }, [title, description, keywords]); // Rerun when props change

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      {/* Page content */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SEOPage;

Explanation:

document.title updates the page title.
Meta tags (description, keywords) are either updated if they already exist or created if they don’t.
The useEffect hook ensures that every time the component renders (or its props change), the title and meta tags are updated in the document head.

Important Points:

This approach will dynamically update the title and meta tags in the DOM for client-side navigation. However, search engine crawlers generally do not execute JavaScript, so these changes will not be reflected in the actual source page unless using SSR (Server-Side Rendering) or pre-rendering.
Without SSR, client-side rendering with dynamic meta tags might still help with some JavaScript-powered search engines (like Google), but is not a full SEO solution.

For full SEO optimizations, consider server-side rendering (SSR) solutions like Next.js, which allows React to generate pre-rendered HTML that search engines can index.
